# What is the preferred image size for List items in a mobile application?

Tags: mobile, user-behavior, lists, mobile-application, photos

First of all we are talking about a Real Estate application where the user is presented with a List full of apartments. Each list item has a Photo, Title, Price and the classic favorite icon.

Recently I had a disagreement with a colleague of mine. In my opinion our mobile list view should have large photos so that users can have a clear look of the apartments, while the other opinion is that the photos must be smaller. When i asked him why he insists on smaller photos he told me that with this way the user can scan the list items faster.

To settle our disagreement we are wondering whether any research or studies exist that indicate which approach is actually preferred by users?

Comment: This question really needs A LOT more info in order to be answered

Comment: @Devin i edited the answer a bit, made it specifically for mobile and list items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you choose list view then the image should be thumbnail size. Show the full image onhover of the thumbnail.

If the primary goal is to show bigger image then it's better move towards card view or tile view (Pinterest )

Attached some mockup for reference
[image]

Comment: This answer seems correct because in the case that you're using a ListView, the image needs to only be complementary to the text and should not overpower the list. If image is the primary concern, then you could go for a different view such as GridView.

Comment: @SwapnilBorkar yes I agree and that's the reason I recommended both the option.

Answer (score 2):

This is a good article/research by NN Group. It also helped me in one of the projects of mine in the e-commerce space. I personally feel the images should be large and the following article/research suggests the same. Also, design is really context specific so it really depends on your specific scenario. Hope this helps.

[Ecommerce UX: 3 Design Trends to Follow and 3 to Avoid](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/e-commerce-usability/)

Comment: Welcome to the site, @Saurabh. To help prevent link rot, it's a good practice to summarize the content of linked articles in your posts here. What would you say are the key points made by the article you've linked?

Comment: @Graham, I will edit this answer with the summary. I will also keep this in mind while answering questions from next time. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the type of your content and how do you want users to focus on them. do you have a lot of content and you want users to scroll and scan them fast? or do you want them to focus on each image?

Example: If it's a gallery of cloth images, the details are important so you should use larger images. Or consider Tinder app. the image is the main content and it's important to see one at a time an it's important to focus on one item at a time.

Another example: If it's a list of songs with their album arts, the image is not the main content and could be smaller.